# java smack 4.0.3 library facebook login error

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, smack, asmack

Connect to Facebook using smack 4.0.3 java api I want to. There was an error "login" function

```
ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("chat.facebook.com",5222);
config.setReconnectionAllowed(true);
config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.enabled);
config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
connection.connect();
connection.login("aaaaa", "passss");
```

output:

> Ağu 27, 2014 9:40:34 PM org.jivesoftware.smack.filter.IQReplyFilter accept
>   WARNING: Rejected potentially spoofed reply to IQ-packet. Filter settings: packetId=hR95T-0, to=null, local=null, server=chat.facebook.com. Received packet with from=aaaaa@chat.facebook.com
>   Ağu 27, 2014 9:40:39 PM test.main login
>   SEVERE: null
>   org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException
>       at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketCollector.nextResultOrThrow(PacketCollector.java:177)
>       at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketCollector.nextResultOrThrow(PacketCollector.java:161)
>       at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.bindResourceAndEstablishSession(XMPPConnection.java:530)
>       at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.login(XMPPTCPConnection.java:260)
>       at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:442)
>       at test.main.login(main.java:135)
>       at test.main.main(main.java:62)

Answer (score 0):

You can not login to Facebook with Smack. Smack is used to connect to [public XMPP servers](https://xmpp.net/directory.php) or a local server. To login Facebook you need to use its [API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.1).